# Need to know how fork works?

Tags: c, process, fork

I am trying the following C code:

```
int main()
{
    printf("text1\n");
    fork();
    printf("text2\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to get the output where i get two "text1" and two "text2", like:

```
text1
text1
text2
text2
```

But, i am, instead, getting:

```
text1
text2
text2
```

only one "text1"???
Ok, if child process executes from the fork(), then why do i get two "text1" for following:

```
int main()  
{  
    printf("text1");  
    fork();  
    printf("text2\n");  
    return 0;  
}
```

the output now is:

```
text1text2  
text1text2
```

If the child process starts after the fork, output should be:

```
text1  
text2  
text2
```

Comment: Why would you expect two copies of "text1"? There is only *one* process until you hit the `fork`.

Comment: @user749391: The code works as expected. Questions like your cannot be answered meaningfully until you actually explain *why* you expect to see two "text1".

Comment: check [this](http://ideone.com/2Mrfv5). it giving output as text1<br>text2<br>text1<br>text2. Why there is such a difference

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`fork()` creates a new process by copying everything in the current process into the new process.  That typically includes everything in memory and the current values of the CPU registers with some minor adjustments.  So in effect, the new process gets a copy of the process's instruction pointer as well so it resumes at the same point where the original process would continue (the instruction following the `fork()`).

---

To address your update, `printf()` is buffered.  Normally the buffer is flushed when it encounters a newline character at the end, `'\n'`.  However since you have omitted this, the contents of the buffer stays and is not flushed.  In the end, both processes (the original and the child) will have the output buffer with `"text1"` in it.  When it eventually gets flushed, you'll see this in both processes.

In practice, you should always flush files and all buffers (that includes `stdout`) before forking to ensure that this does not happen.

```
printf("text1");
fflush(stdout);
fork();
```

The output should look like this (in some order):

```
text1text2
text2
```

Comment: But why do i get two "text1" for following:

int main()  
{  
    printf("text1");  
    fork();  
    printf("text2\n");  
    return 0;  
}  

the output now is:

text1text2  
text1text2  

If the child process starts after the fork, output should be:

text1  
text2  
text2

Comment: What an explanation. WOW.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The forked process gets a copy of the variable memory, and at the time of the fork the output buffer has yet to be flushed. No output has been written to the console when you fork, only buffered up. Both processes thus continues with text1 already in the buffer, and thus both print it.

Comment: @adi, To get the expected output you should put `fflush(stdout)` after the first printf

Answer (score 6):

`fork` clones the current process. The new process will "start" at the `fork` call, not at the start of `main` as you seem to expect. Thus when you print the first time there is 1 process, then when you fork there are two.

Since you are `fork`ing after printing `"text1"`, it is only printed once.

In the second example the duplicated output is due to output buffering - printf doesn't actually output anything to the screen until it is flushed or it hits a newline (`'\n'`).

Consequently the first call to `printf` actually just wrote data to a buffer somewhere, the data was then copied into the second process' address space, and then the second call to `printf` would have flushed the buffer, complete with `"text1"` in both buffers.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `fork`ed process starts after `fork`, not from very beginning. `exec` starts process from entry point and will print what you expect.

Comment: i still cant get it, cuz when I remove "\n" from the 1st printf(), i m getting "text1" twice as well, i.e.
int main()
{
    printf("text1");
    fork();
    printf("text2\n");
    return 0;
}
the output is:
text1text2
text1text2

Comment: I would guess in that case that both the original and forked processes inherit the buffered output with "text1" since the end-of-line hasn't caused the buffer to flush.  I'd assume if you did a flush on stdout prior to the fork you'd see what you expect to see.

Answer (score 1):

The child process will start from the position of the fork(), so you are getting the correct output.

Comment: as u said, child process will start from fork(), i should get
text1text2  
text2, in second case

Answer (score 1):

```
Problem 1 : the output as
      text1
      text2
      text2
```

This is because fork() create exact copy (child) of parent process and both processes start their execution right after the system call fork().

```
Problem 2 : the output as
      text1text2 
      text1text2
```

This is all about buffering. Refer this link and learn about fork() basics.
http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html

Answer (score 0):

from `man 2 fork`: fork returns 0 to the child process.

```
value = fork();
if( value == -1 ) {
  printf( "fork failed\n" );
  exit(1);
}
if( value ) {
  printf( "test1\n" );
} else {
  printf( "test2\n" };
}
```