# Need to know how fork works

Tags: c, process, fork

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to know how fork works???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011635/need-to-know-how-fork-works)

I am trying the following C code:

```
int main()  
{  
    printf("text1\n");  
    fork();  
    printf("text2\n");  
    return 0;  
}
```

I was expecting to get the output where i get two "text1" and two "text2", like:

```
text1  
text1  
text2  
text2
```

But, i am, instead, getting:

```
text1  
text2  
text2
```

only one "text1"??? If child process executes from the fork(), then why do i get two "text1" for following:

```
int main()  
{  
    printf("text1");  
    fork();  
    printf("text2\n");  
    return 0;  
}
```

the output now is:

```
text1text2  
text1text2
```

If the child process starts after the fork, output should be:

```
text1text2  
text2
```