# How to run linux terminal command in python in new terminal

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I read multiple answers regarding how to run the linux shell command using subprocess module in python. In my case, i need to run linux shell commands inside my python code in such a way that these commands should get executed in new terminal.

```
subprocess.call(["df","-h"]
```

I'm running say xyz.py in base terminal, when i execute above command, it overwrites on the output of xyz.py in the same terminal. I want this command to be executed in different terminal, or i want to store output of this command in a text file.

```
subprocess.call(["df","-h",">","somefile.txt"])
```

Above command is not working.

Edit-1:
If i save the output in a text file, i also have to display it through python.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pipe a subprocess call to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856583/how-do-i-pipe-a-subprocess-call-to-a-text-file)

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess
fp = open("somefile.txt", "w")
subprocess.run(["df", "-h"], stdout=fp)
fp.close
```

Use a file handle.

If you want to print the output while saving it:

```
import subprocess
cp = subprocess.run(["df", "-h"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(cp.stdout)
fp = open("somefile.txt", "w")
print(cp.stdout, file=fp)
fp.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. Problem is, if i save it in a text file, i also have to display it using python.

Comment: @spectre You can use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to get the stdout, print it and then save it to the file.

Comment: Even before running the code, it shows error with "print(cp.out, file=fp)" line.

Comment: @spectre It's a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: Still it shows same error. Can you please check once and edit it. Thanks.

Comment: @spectre Is it Python 2 or Python 3? I'm not familiar with Python 2.

Comment: It's not working in python3. It prints random data from the file.

Comment: Is it working in your compiler? Can you please check the syntax once?

Comment: @spectre What Python version are you using?

Comment: I'm using inbuilt Python 3 version in linux.

Comment: @spectre That's not enough. Which Python 3 version? 3.5 or 3.6 (or else)? Different "minor" versions can differ *a lot* in behavior in certain circumstances.

Comment: It's python 3.5.2

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the os.system?

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'your command'")
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem with this is, new terminal is getting opened. But it's unable to execute the command inside new terminal

Comment: And what about creating a child with os.fork?

Comment: os.system(" gnome-terminal  -e '['df','-h']' ")
This is what i did. What corrections do you suggest?

Comment: I think this works fine, but if you want you can try fork to create a child (new process). See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560802/pythonhow-os-fork-works

Comment: The correct syntax is `os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'df -h'")` or better `subprocess.run(["gnome-terminal", "-e", "df -h"])`

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("somefile.txt", "w")
subprocess.run(["df","-h"], stdout = file)
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'gedit somefile.txt' ")
```

Above code is working. If there are any simple/efficient way to do the same it'll be helpful.