# Does Python Multiprocessing Copy All Modules From The Parent?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I noticed that I can access functions and modules in a child process that were outside of the child process function/target. So I'm wondering when I create a child process in python does it copy everything from current process? Why is it I can access functions and imported modules that are outside the child target?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def test1():
         return "hello"

def simpleChildProcess( childPipe ):
       # simpleChildProcess can access test1 function
       foo = test1()
       childPipe.send( foo )

parentPipe, childPipe = Pipe()
childProcess = Process( target=simpleChildProcess, args=(childPipe,) )

childProcess.start()

print "Pipe Contains: %s" % parentPipe.recv()
```

Answer (score 7):

On Unix-like OSes, `multiprocessing.Process` [uses `os.fork`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33560802/190597) to spawn new processes.
`fork` creates a new process which is a copy of the parent process, and the forked process resumes from the point where `fork` was called.

Since Windows lacks `fork`, `multiprocessing.Process` starts a new Python process and imports the calling module. On Windows, calls to `Process` have to be inside `if __name__ == '__main__'` to prevent `Process` from being called repeatedly every time the calling module is imported. (It's a good practice even on Unix to include `if __name__ == '__main__':` to prevent your code from causing runaway process-spawning).

Thus, the child process has access to functions and modules that have been defined by the calling module *up to the point* where `Process` had been called (in the case of Unix) or after importation of the calling module (in the case of Windows).

Comment: thank you. I thought this might be the case. wouldn't it be more resource efficient to use a python subprocess to create a child process if I only wanted to run a function?

Comment: well explained. I encountered many weird scenarios on Windows and this puts it well ordered in my head

Comment: @Jack: [Linux uses copy-on-write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13128386/190597) (though I'm not sure about all Unix-likes). Thus, although forking appears to copy all data from parent to child, a physical copy is not made until the data is modified. So for OSes with copy-on-write, `forking` is not excessively resource intensive. If the parent process uses a lot of resources and the OS does not use copy-on-write, then using `subprocess.Popen` could be less resource intensive.

Comment: note you can instruct `multiprocessing` to spawn new processes (instead of forking) by explicitly [setting a start method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods)

Comment: @unutbu thank you. I had forgotten all about copy on write, and I do believe most Unix OSs do this.

Comment: Thank you @SamMason, but I don't see this option list in the docs for python2, although it might be available.

Comment: @Jack note that Python 2 is officially [retiring in a few months](https://pythonclock.org/) and hence you should be trying to move away from it

Comment: Apparently OSX while being unix-like (depending on definition) does not seem to fork. Meaning, module variables are not copied to subprocesses as they are on linux.